# Understanding difference between zip and combineLatest with RxSwift for sequence parameters

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have used two functions. First `combineLatest`:

```
        enum Weather {
            case cloudy
            case sunny
        }
        let left: Observable<Weather> = Observable.of(.sunny, .cloudy, .cloudy, .sunny)
        let right = Observable.of("Lisbon", "Copenhagen", "London", "Madrid", "Vienna")
        let observable = Observable.combineLatest(left, right) { weather, city in
            return "It's \(weather) in \(city)"
        }
        _ = observable.subscribe(onNext: { value in
            print(value)
        })
```

with output:

```
It's sunny in Lisbon
It's cloudy in Lisbon
It's cloudy in Copenhagen
It's cloudy in Copenhagen
It's cloudy in London
It's sunny in London
It's sunny in Madrid
It's sunny in Vienna
```

and `zip`:

```
        enum Weather {
            case cloudy
            case sunny
        }
        let left: Observable<Weather> = Observable.of(.sunny, .cloudy, .cloudy, .sunny)
        let right = Observable.of("Lisbon", "Copenhagen", "London", "Madrid", "Vienna")
        let observable = Observable.zip(left, right) { weather, city in
            return "It's \(weather) in \(city)"
        }
        _ = observable.subscribe(onNext: { value in
            print(value)
        })
```

with output:

```
It's sunny in Lisbon
It's cloudy in Copenhagen
It's cloudy in London
It's sunny in Madrid
```

How does it work? I understand that zip just map values one to one, and if there is no value for same index, it just skip it. But how to understand `combineLatest`?

Comment: You might find this article helpful: [Recipes for Combining Observables in RxSwift](https://danielt1263.medium.com/recipes-for-combining-observables-in-rxswift-ec4f8157265f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`combineLatest` is a bit easier to understand (and more useful!) if the two observables don't emit elements *immediately*. An easier-to-understand example (which I encourage you to try) is:

```
Observable.combineLatest(someUISwitch.rx.isOn, someUITextField.rx.text) { isOn, text in
    return "Text: \(text ?? ""), Switch is on: \(isOn)"
}.subscribe(onNext: { value in
    print(value)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Try adding a `UISwitch` and a `UITextField` into your UI. Now try entering some text into the text field, and also try switching the switch. You will see that whenever one of the two changes, that is, when either observable emits a new value, their combined value (combined by the closure passed to `combineLatest`) gets emitted by the combined observable.

More generally, the observable produced by `combineLatest` emits its first value when all the observables first emits a value, and subsequent values are emitted when any of the observables emits a value. Whenever it emits a value, the value it emits is computed by combining all the *latest* values that all the observables have emitted. Hence "combine latest".

For your `Observable.of` example, the values are all emitted immediately, but `combineLatest` behaves as if `left` and `right` emits values in an interlaced order, and `left` goes first. I've tried to add annotations to the output you got. See if this helps your understanding.

```
    (left emits sunny)
    (right emits Lisbon)
It's sunny in Lisbon (the first values emitted by both observables)
    (left emits cloudy)
It's cloudy in Lisbon
    (right emits Copenhagen)
It's cloudy in Copenhagen
    (left emits 2nd cloudy)
It's cloudy in Copenhagen
    (right emits London)
It's cloudy in London
    (left emits sunny)
It's sunny in London
    (right emits Madrid)
It's sunny in Madrid
    (right emits Vienna, since left ran out)
It's sunny in Vienna
```

Also, don't forget there's [RxMarbles](https://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest) that you can play with.

Comment: Oh, now I understand it better. So it assumes the latest from both observables, not the latest from every one of them separately. Thank you.